# Criar tabuada dinâmica dentro de uma tabela criada em tempo execução - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Bom, o intuito desse exercicio que estava realizando era trabalhar com o elemento table de forma dinamica, adicionando os valores de 1 a 10 no thead e o calculo matematico abaixo. Porém o resultados das expressões matematicas são diferentes e ficam disponibilizados em ordem contraria.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tabuada</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabuada">
       
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>

    var novaTabela = document.createElement('table');
    var header = novaTabela.createTHead();
    var rowHeader = header.insertRow(0);
    
    var body = document.createElement('tbody');

    document.getElementById('tabuada').append(novaTabela);
    novaTabela.append(body);
    
    for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
        var th = document.createElement('th');
        th = rowHeader.appendChild(th);
        th.innerHTML = x;
        
        var rowBody = body.insertRow();
        
        for (var y = 1; y <= 10; y++) {
            rowBody.insertCell(0).innerHTML = `${x} x ${y} = ${x*y}`;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/pwsz8gad/

Answer (score -1):

O código tem o seguinte erro, ao adicionar a coluna usando insertCell(0) ele está adicionando na frente, e não por último, assim o for deveria ser invertido, tal como fiz abaixo:

```
var novaTabela = document.createElement('table');
    var header = novaTabela.createTHead();
    var rowHeader = header.insertRow(0);
    
    var body = document.createElement('tbody');

    document.getElementById('tabuada').append(novaTabela);
    novaTabela.append(body);
    
    for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
        var th = document.createElement('th');
        th = rowHeader.appendChild(th);
        th.innerHTML = x;
        
        var rowBody = body.insertRow();
        
        for (var y = 10; y > 0; y--) {
            rowBody.insertCell(0).innerHTML = `${x} x ${y} = ${x*y}`;
        }
    }
```